# View/query custom event in Azure application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, hockeyapp, ms-app-analytics

I am using hockey application to distribute mobile application.

[image]

I need to see their additional properties and it say I need to link with azure application insights. I have already done that. Inside there, I also saw my custom event with properties. Problem is that I don't know how to query all my custom event with their payload. How can I write script? One of my event name is called "VIEW_MEDIA".

I have used this query command to get report for VIEW_MEDIA but it doesn't give me their properties.

```
customEvents | where name startswith "VIEW_MEDIA" | summarize count() by name | render piechart
```

Comment: Are custom properties not stored in the customDimension property of a customEvent? What does `customEvents | project customDimension` tell?

Comment: (or more specficially `customEvents | where name starswith "VIEW_MEDIA" | project customDimensions, customMeasurements | limit 10`, which will filter your data down, get *only* custom properties and metrics, and limit to just 10 rows.  then you can expand those fields (json) and figure out what else you might need from inside those fields.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is working.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the `summarize count() by name` part, you're basically removing all data from the result except for the event names and their respective count.

If you want the query to summarize by some property, you can run a query similar to this:

```
customEvents 
| where name starswith "VIEW_MEDIA" 
| extend myProperty = tostring(customDimensions.MyProperty) 
| summarize count() by name, myProperty 
| render ...
```

Comment: I cannot see custom data with that query though.

Comment: To see the raw data, drop the summarize part (and everything after it)